# Undefined Index $_GET

Tags: php, sql, get, indexing, undefined

1st Page that links to the 2nd

```
<td><a href="moreToysDetail.php?toyInfo=<?=$currentToy["toy_id"];?>">More Detail</a></td>
```

2nd Page

```
$toyId=$_GET["toyInfo"];

$question = "SELECT * FROM toy, toyscountry, toysmedia, alltoyscategory WHERE toy_id= '$toyId' AND   toy.toy_country = toyscountry.tCou_id
                                                                     AND toy.toy_id = toysmedia.tMedia_toyId 
                                                                     AND toy.toy_id=alltoyscategory.allToysCat_toyId";
$reply = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $question);
echo $question;
```

> ERROR FOUND AFTER ECHO
>   Notice: Undefined index: toyInfo in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\CA1\moreToysDetail.php on line 5
>   SELECT * FROM toy, toyscountry, toysmedia, alltoyscategory WHERE toy_id= AND toy.toy_country = toyscountry.tCou_id AND toy.toy_id = toysmedia.tMedia_toyId AND toy.toy_id=alltoyscategory.allToysCat_toyId

They couldnt detect toyInfo :( Any kind souls that can help? Greatly appreaciated, I need to hand in my assignment in a few hours time >.<

Comment: what does your HTML form look like. Does it have an input field named "toyinfo"?

Comment: <td><a href="moreToysDetail.php?toyInfo=<?=$currentToy["toy_id"];?>">More Detail</a></td> yup it looks like this(if this is what you mean :)

Comment: Yeah, that looks correct. What do you get for output of a print_r($_GET); ?

Comment: Does $current_toy['toy_id'] have a value?

Comment: @databyss i got this Notice: Undefined index: toyInfo in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\CA1\moreToysDetail.php on line 5
Array ( )

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yup its something to do with the database, a table's primary key, well its a number

Comment: Does your site use some sort of URL rewriter that's converting your URL into something like site.com/moreToysDetail/5? It looks like your $_GET variable is empty.

Comment: yeap! but it works for other links though, just not this one :/ @databyss

Comment: If the url is getting rewritten, you'll need to parse it out of the url, instead of $_GET, because it won't be there. Echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to see what you get for that.

Comment: um, i which part of the code am i suppose put that in? (:

Comment: echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
to see if that's what is happening.

Comment: issit put that in below the $reply? the one that i put echo $question? do i have to delete the $toyId=$_GET["toyInfo"]; then? sorry abit slow yah

Answer (score 2):

I spot 3 things that might be wrong with your code:

**first:**

```
<td><a href="moreToysDetail.php?toyInfo=<?=$currentToy["toy_id"];?>">More Detail</a></td>
```

should look like

```
<td><a href="moreToysDetail.php?toyInfo=<? echo $currentToy["toy_id"];?>">More Detail</a></td>
```

This assumes your php is configured to accept the shorthand `<?` in stead of the default `<?php`

**second:**

is your toy id in the databse not stored as an integer? It pobably should, as it is best practice for an id. This means you don't need the single quotes in you SQL statement:

```
...  WHERE toy_id= $toyId AND ...
```

**third:**

Your final line of code does not make much sense. You are echoing the SQL statement. I believe you'ld want to echo the reply. Have a look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php to find out how to do this, as the reply currently holds an object that you can not just use echo on to display the data.

Comment: $reply is a result resource, not a string or array. echoing that won't be of much help. The OP needs to fetch rows from it.

Comment: that is absolutly true. Sorry, my 'pure' php is a bit rusty, I'm used to working with a framework that handles this for me. Feel free to correct my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a unexpected "=" so that must have  been the problem, you also needed to echo $currentToy["toy_id"];

```
<td><a href="moreToysDetail.php?toyInfo=<? echo $currentToy["toy_id"]; ?>">More Detail</a></td>
```

Comment: *"Try this:"* is a [subpar answer decoration](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help10). Instead please add a slim explanation of *what* your code does, *why* you'd recommend it, or *how* you came to the conclusion.

Comment: hi i couldnt tag you i dont know where to find your name, new user yeah -.- but thanks! there's no error no more. BUT! it still could not be displayed :(